# Overriding css properties between files

Tags: css

I have two CSS files `test1.css` and `test2.css` as seen below:

**test1.css**

```
body {
  background: blue;
}
```

**test2.css**

```
body {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

I imported both the CSS files in my `test.html` using:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=“test1.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=“test2.css" />
```

I don’t want the `background` & other CSS properties to be applied in my `body`, I want only the `font-weight` to be applied.

Comment: Either remove the link to the first stylesheet or define a background for body in the second stylesheet.

Comment: I think you should add class for this rather then call different css for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test2.css file, you could use `all:initial` on `body` to discard all CSS, apart from unicode-bidi and direction, coming from test1.css for `body`.

```
body {
  all: initial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Read up: [`all` - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

> The CSS all shorthand property resets all properties, apart from unicode-bidi and direction, to their initial or inherited value.

Comment: If you care about IE, and all but the latest safari you will need a different approach: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all

Comment: I need IE as well, please tell me what should I do to support IE

Comment: @user123 try `all: inherit`

Comment: @Rahul Desai  As JonP said, 'all' property doesn't support IE, so I believe all: inherit also doesn't support